# cannot access jakart.servlet.filter in java maven project

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-migration

Getting the error `cannot access jakarta.servlet.Filter` when running `mvn clean install` and getting
`class file for jakarta.servlet.Filter not found` when trying to run. This seems to have started after moving from javax to jakarta, including updating my classes to use the jakarta namespace instead of the javax namespace, EXCEPT for in the case of javax.servlet, which can't be replaced with jakarta.servlet in any class because it's not found. I assume this is because `mvn clean install` never finishes due to the error?

${jackson.Version} is 2.14.0-rc1 and ${springVersion} is 2.7.5

NOTE: the `spring-boot-starter-web` dependency is already present and does not resolve the issue.

```
<dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
                <version>${jackson.Version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
                <version>${jackson.Version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
                <version>${jackson.Version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-modules-java8</artifactId>
                <version>${jackson.Version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.lmax</groupId>
                <artifactId>disruptor</artifactId>
                <version>3.4.4</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.vlkan.log4j2</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j2-logstash-layout</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.5</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
                <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
                <version>4.0.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
                <version>4.0.4</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>jakarta.validation</groupId>
                <artifactId>jakarta.validation-api</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>jakarta.annotation</groupId>
                <artifactId>ca-parent</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.5</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-csv</artifactId>
                <version>1.9.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-text</artifactId>
                <version>1.10.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
                <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
                <version>4.5.13</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-1.2-api</artifactId>
                <version>${log4j.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
                <version>${log4j.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
                <version>${log4j.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-jcl</artifactId>
                <version>${log4j.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-jul</artifactId>
                <version>${log4j.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
                <version>${log4j.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.4.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
                <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
                <version>5.2.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
                <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
                <version>5.2.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
                <version>9.0.68</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.6</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.javers</groupId>
                <artifactId>javers-spring-boot-starter-mongo</artifactId>
                <version>6.6.5</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jeasy</groupId>
                <artifactId>easy-rules-core</artifactId>
                <version>4.1.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jeasy</groupId>
                <artifactId>easy-rules-support</artifactId>
                <version>4.1.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
                <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.6</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
                <version>${springVersion}</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
                <version>${springVersion}</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
                <version>${springVersion}</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
                <version>${springVersion}</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
                <version>${springVersion}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
                <version>${springVersion}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                <version>6.0.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
                <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
                <version>1.33</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.example.pdp.test</groupId>
                <artifactId>testing-utils-common-spring</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.0</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.github.stefanbirkner</groupId>
                <artifactId>system-rules</artifactId>
                <version>1.19.0</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
                <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
                <version>6.11.0</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
                <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
                <version>6.11.0</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
                <artifactId>cucumber-spring</artifactId>
                <version>6.11.0</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                <version>5.8.2</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
                        <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                <version>${springVersion}</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>pl.project13.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>git-commit-id-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>4.0.5</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

Here's my plugin section:

```
       <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>enforce-versions</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>enforce</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <rules>
                                <requireMavenVersion>
                                    <version>3.3.9</version>
                                </requireMavenVersion>
                                <requireJavaVersion>
                                    <version>1.11</version>
                                </requireJavaVersion>
                            </rules>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jxr-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <destDir>${project.build.directory}/site/sourceRefs</destDir>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jxr</goal>
                            <goal>test-jxr</goal>
                            <goal>aggregate</goal>
                            <goal>test-aggregate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>initialize</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>pmd</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <xrefLocation>${project.build.directory}/site/sourceRefs</xrefLocation>
                    <aggregate>true</aggregate>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <show>private</show>
                    <nohelp>true</nohelp>
                    <failOnError>true</failOnError>
                    <sourceFileExcludes>
                        <exclude>**/idq/**</exclude>
                    </sourceFileExcludes>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>javadoc-no-fork</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>bundle-sources</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar-no-fork</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>initialize</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>create</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <timestampFormat>{0,date,yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z}</timestampFormat>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifestFile>${project.build.outputDirectory}/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF</manifestFile>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <release>17</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>cucumber/**/*</include>
                    </includes>
                    <skip>${skipIT}</skip>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
                    <argLine>@{argLine} -Xmx1024m --illegal-access=permit</argLine>
                    <useSystemClassLoader>false</useSystemClassLoader>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>cucumber/**/*</exclude>
                        <exclude>${sonar.exclusions}</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                    <skip>${skipUT}</skip>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <linkXRef>true</linkXRef>
                    <xrefLocation>${project.build.directory}/site/sourceRefs</xrefLocation>
                    <aggregate>true</aggregate>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report-only</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>com/example/provider/exampleapi/ApplicationLauncher.java</excludes>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-prepare-agent</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>check</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>check</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <rules>
                                <rule>
                                    <element>BUNDLE</element>
                                    <limits>
                                        <limit>
                                            <counter>CLASS</counter>
                                            <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
                                            <minimum>${code.coverage.requirement}</minimum>
                                        </limit>
                                        <limit>
                                            <counter>METHOD</counter>
                                            <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
                                            <minimum>${code.coverage.requirement}</minimum>
                                        </limit>
                                        <limit>
                                            <counter>BRANCH</counter>
                                            <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
                                            <minimum>${code.coverage.requirement}</minimum>
                                        </limit>
                                        <limit>
                                            <counter>LINE</counter>
                                            <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
                                            <minimum>${code.coverage.requirement}</minimum>
                                        </limit>
                                    </limits>
                                </rule>
                            </rules>
                            <skip>${skipUT}</skip>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>report</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <localCheckout>true</localCheckout>
                    <pushChanges>false</pushChanges>
                    <goals>deploy</goals>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>checkstyle-check-aggregate</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <configLocation>/example.checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
                            <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                            <consoleOutput>true</consoleOutput>
                            <failsOnError>false</failsOnError>
                            <enableRSS>false</enableRSS>
                            <excludes>**/com/example/provider/exampleapi/model/idq/**/*</excludes>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>checkstyle</goal>
                            <goal>checkstyle-aggregate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                <goals>
                    <goal>site</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <generateReports>false</generateReports>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>initialize</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>site</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <schemaLanguage>WSDL</schemaLanguage>
                    <generatePackage>com.example.exampleapi.model.idq</generatePackage>
                    <schemas>
                        <schema>
                            <url>
                                https://examplewebservice.example.com/ExampleService/WebService/ws_Rule/
                            </url>
                        </schema>
                    </schemas>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>pl.project13.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>git-commit-id-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <offline>true</offline>
                    <failOnNoGitDirectory>false</failOnNoGitDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
```

Comment: You need Spring Boot 3.0.0 for `jakarta.servlet` support. Also, Spring Boot 3.0.0 requires Java 17.

Comment: Gotcha! I am using Java 17 but when I try 3.0.0 I get ```Unsupported targetJdk value '17'```. Any idea what might be up with that? Thanks!

Comment: at which stage do you fall with `Unsupported targetJdk value '17'`?

Comment: PMD. I tried what this suggests: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-pmd-plugin/examples/upgrading-PMD-at-runtime.html to no avail. It results in the same ```cannot access jakarta.servlet.Filter``` error. I can add my plugins section to the post.

Comment: as I don't see a version number for the pmd plugin, probably you should try to specify a recent version of it (3.19.0 is the most recent one at the time I write this comment). And btw: you could drop all those group definitions for mavens own plugins.

Comment: but if it's really about PMD, you probably should ask a new version here and tag it accordingly

Comment: I think the ```Unsupported targetJdk value '17'``` problem was solved by updating intelliJ from 2020 to 2022. As for the ```jakarta.servlet.Filter``` error, I don't think it's a PMD problem, I specified the version number and it seems to have made no difference. Also thanks for the advice!